# Absolutely continuous and almost everywhere solution of a controlled dynamical system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory, almost-everywhere

This is a doubt i had while reading the first chapter form the book **Mathematical Control Theory, Jerzy Zabczyk**, in the first chapter, page $11$ the author talks about solution for a class of differential equations:

Consider the system of differential equations $$\frac{dq}{dt}=A(t)q(t)+a(t),~~q(t_0)=q_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$$
on a fixed interval $[0,T]$; $t_0 \in [0,T]$ where $A \in M(n,n)$ i.e space of all $n \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{R}$, $A(t)=[a_{ij}, i=1,\ldots,n,j=1,\ldots,m]$, $a(t) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ defined as $a(t)=(a_i(t),i=1,\ldots,n)$, whete $t \in [0,T]$. Now he states the theorem

**Theorem :** Assume the elements of the function $A(\cdot)$ are locally integrable. Then there exists exactly one function $S(t)~,~t\in [0,T]$ with values in $M(n,n)$ and with absolutely continuous elements such that $$\begin{align}\frac{d}{dt}S(t)&=A(t)S(t)~~,~~\text{for almost all}~t\in [0,T] \\S(0)&=I \end{align}$$ In addition, a matrix $S(t)$ is invertible for an arbitrary $t \in [0,T]$, and the unique solution of the equation $(1)$ is of the form $$q(t)=S(t)S^{-1}(t_0)q_0+\int_{t_0}^tS(t)S^{-1}(s)a(s)ds,~t\in[0,T]$$ The proof is not that hard to follow, he uses Banach's Fixed point theorem for the firt part , and the second part need some work but doable. But what confuses me are the parts **Almost everywhere** and **absolutely continuous** in the statement of the theorem, what does these terms mean actually in this context, i'm not able to follow these two definitions. Will be thankful if someone provides a easy definition for these. Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't go to much detail, for a detailed exposition a course in *measure theory* would be helpful i feel. Control theory really hinges on the notion of *Caratheodory solution of differential equations* as opposed to the standard differential equations with Lipschitz right-hand sides, as i said earlier complete understanding of this concept requires measure theory, for our purposes, however, it's enough to know a few things from basic analysis.

In basics of Lebesgue integration theory it is enough to think of a Lebesgue measurable real-valued function on an interval as a piecewise constant function or the pointwise limit of a piecewise constant function. For instance, $$[0,1]∋t↦\text{sgn}(\cos(2πnt))$$ is a Lebesgue measurable discontinuous function for each $n>0$, the Dirichlet comb (i.e the indicator of rationals) $$[0,1]∋t↦\chi_{\mathbb{Q}}(t)=\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{Q}}(t) := \left\{
\begin{aligned}1  ~~~~~  &t \in\mathbb{Q}\\0~~~~~&\text{else}\end{aligned}
\right. $$ is a Lebesgue measurable function that is "almost everywhere" zero (except a set of *measure zero*), so it is equivalent to the zero function. If you can inject  $\chi_{\mathbb{Q}}(t)$ as a control input of a system i.e $\mathbb{R} \ni t\mapsto u(t):=\chi_{\mathbb{Q}}(t)$, its response will be identical to its response corresponding to the zero control. Moreover, the set of Lebesgue measurable functions on an interval constitutes a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ when equipped with pointwise addition and scalar multiplication operations.

An absolutely continuous function is very close to a continuously differentiable function, so it's enough to substitute "continuously differentiable" in place of "absolutely continuous". For instance, the triangle function $$[0,1]∋t↦T(t) := \left\{
\begin{aligned}t  ~~~~~  &\text{if}~~t \in [0,1/2]\\1-t~~~~~&\text{if}~~t \in~]1/2,1]\end{aligned}
\right. $$ is absolutely continuous but not continuously differentiable. The defining characteristic of an absolutely continuous function is that they're expressible as integrals of other, more *rough* functions. You may view the process of integration be it Lebesgue or Riemann, as a smoothing operation: typically, rough functions become less rough upon integration. Absolutely continuous functions are very close to functions of bounded variation, if you can write down a given function as an integral as in $$f(t)=a+\int_b^t g(s)\,\mathrm{d}s$$ for some other function $g$, then $f$ is absolutely continuous. For instance, for the triangle function, $a=0$, $c=0$ and $$[0,1]∋t↦g(t) := \left\{
\begin{aligned}t  ~~~~~  &\text{if}~~1 \in [0,1/2[\\-1~~~~~&\text{if}~~t \in~[1/2,1]\end{aligned}
\right. $$

Comment: Thanks for answering. This is very clear

Answer (score 2):

The matrix $A$ is a generalized function, its values can be changed on any null set without changing it, that is, without leaving the equivalence class of ordinary functions that make up $A$. Any claims involving values of $A$ can only be "a.e."

["absolutely continuous"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Definition) is the strongest regularity you can get in an anti-derivative of a locally integrable function. It replaces the differentiability you would get if $A$ were continuous.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Why do you call $A$ a generalized function? i think the solution involves the complete linear space i.e the banach space $\mathbb{R}^n$ with some norm, are you talking about the matrix valued function $S$ ?

Comment: Because the space $L^1_{loc}$ consists of such equivalence classes, this has nothing to do with the structure of the range space.